# Number of rows from tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I was working with the tableview and I wanted the number of rows (i.e the number of items in tableview). How can I get the number of rows, if available?

Please help me out,
thanks in advance.

Comment: you are set number of rows in numberOfRowsinSection so you already know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a instance variable in your header file.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {
     yourHeaderFileVariable = [noOfItemsInArray count];
     NSLog(@"total item in table %d",yourHeaderFileVariable);
     return [noOfItemsInArray count];
}
```

or try this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section      {

     NSLog(@"total item in table %d",[noOfItemsInArray count]);
     return [noOfItemsInArray count];
}
```

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: hey thanks , but how to get the variable noOfItemsInArray in an NSInteger variable.

Comment: simple NSInteger count = [yourArray count]; //Note yourArray is referring to an object of NSArray/NSMutableArray. if you call [yourArray count] method this method will return an NSInteger if you want to see waht the method returns see documentation of NSArray/NSMutableArray

Comment: hey i did this  NSInteger count= [arrName count] ;
                NSLog(@"items in int %d",count); but im not able print on console

Comment: add a breakpoint in the noofrows method and see if your array is initialized or not.

Comment: @ Rahul Vyas: hey its initialised , i got the value when i tried NSLog(@"total item in table %d",[arrName count]);
     return [arrName count];

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows in table view for a section is what you are returning from `(NSInteger)tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. So if you return something like `[mySource count]` from this method then the number of rows is `[mySource count]`.

For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [data count];
}

// to get the count 
NSInteger rowCount = [data count];
```

Now replace `[data count]` with whatever calculation you have in the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tablefirst numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

int count; 
    count=0;
     count=[*your array name* count]; 
    NSLog(@"row count=%d",count);
return [*your array name* count];
    }
```

Comment: how to get the count in a variable so that i can print it on the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the delegate method :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
return [yourArray count];  
}
```

You can then show the result in the table header by using the following delegate method :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)resultTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[yourArray count]];  
    str=[str stringByAppendingString:@" matches"];  
    return str;  
}
```

For example, if you have 7 results in the table, the header will display the text "7 matches"

Answer (score -1):

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {



        return numberOfRows;
    }
```

Comment: i want the number in a variable so that i can print it on console

Comment: int rowCount = "whatever you want"

Comment: u mean NSInteger * rowCount = "array list"

Comment: int count; count=0; count=[*your array name* count]; NSLog(@"row count=%d",count);

Answer (score -1):

This function returns the number rows(items) in your tableview

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [listOfItems count];
  }
```